# Finding the root of a degree $5$ polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

$\textbf{Question}$: which of the following $\textbf{cannot}$ be a root of a polynomial in $x$ of the form $9x^5+ax^3+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers?

A) $-9$

B) $-5$

C) $\dfrac{1}{4}$

D) $\dfrac{1}{3}$

E) $9$

> I thought about this question for a bit now and can anyone provide any hints because I have no clue how to begin to eliminate the choices?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The hints about the rational root theorem below are perfectly good, but I think it's killing a fly with a cannon: in this case just filling in the possible answers in the polynomials and trying to see if the equation that you get (in $a$ and $b$) is solvable using integers seems like a more obvious approach. For each possible answer, I think you will see whether or not it is possible fairly quickly. Depending on in what context you found this question, it might also be a more appropriate way to try to answer it (e.g., there's no need to learn the rational root theorem for high school math).

Comment: @MeesdeVries Thank you! I will try that.

Comment: The rational root theorem..."a cannon"? I bet the theorem is extremely flattered...Anyway, even assuming time is not an issue, substituting and checking as you propose seems a rather lengthy, boring way to go. Let's see for example what happens with (D): $$\frac9{3^5}+\frac a{3^3}+b = 0\implies 1+a+27b=0$$ Can you see right away whether there's a chance here with $\,a,b\in\Bbb Z\,$ ? What about (C)? $$\frac 9{4^5}+\frac a{4^3}+b=0\implies 9+16a+4^5b=0$$ Is it obvious right away this has no solution with integers? I doubt it...

Comment: @DonAntonio, for (D), yes: we have an $a$ without a coefficient, so any choice for $b$ gives us a choice for $a$ (this one is just as easy as (A), (B), (E), except there the $b$ has no coefficient). Indeed, (C) is the least trivial, but it's not too difficult: we have that $4\mid16a+4^5b$, while $4\not\mid9$, so no solution. This is certainly easier than learning a proof of the rational root theorem if it was not already in your arsenal.

Comment: That theorem's proof is so easy that many times it is proved in high school, so I don't think that's a problem, not to mention that imo this is what was intended in this particular question...but that only my personal view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

If a reduced rational number $\,\frac rs\,$ is a root of an *integer polynomial* $\,a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n\,$ , then

$$r\mid a_0\;,\;\;s\mid a_n$$

The above is called the Rational Root Theorem, sometimes

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Use [Rational Root Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Answer (score 4):

Use the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), and note that the denominator of one of the options given **does not** divide $9$...

Comment: What a toss - up on which answer to accept here! ;-) So, another TU! +1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try process of elimination, an easy place to start is by assuming that either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$.  (Hey, zero is an integer!)

If you set $a = 0$, then you get $b = -9x^5$.  Because $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under multiplication, if $x$ is an integer, then so is $b$, and so you have a valid $(a, b)$ pair with $x$ as a root.  Thus, (A), (B), and (E) cannot be the right answer.  However, for $x = \frac{1}{4}$ or $x = \frac{1}{3}$, you'd get $b = \frac{-9}{1024}$ or $b = \frac{-1}{27}$, respectively, so $b \notin \mathbb{Z}$, and these aren't valid solutions.  So far, (C) and (D) are still possible answer choices.

If you set $b = 0$, then you get $9x^5 + ax^3 = 0$, which factors to $x^3(9x^2+a) = 0$, so either $x = 0$ (which isn't one of the answer choices) or $a = -9x^2$.  If $x = \frac{1}{3}$, then $a = -1$, which is an integer, so that rules out answer choice (D).  But if $x = \frac{1}{4}$, then $a = \frac{-9}{16}$, a non-integer, so (C) is still in the running.

To double-check that (C) is the correct answer, plug in $x = \frac{1}{4}$ into the original equation, to get $\frac{9}{1024} + \frac{1}{64}a + b = 0$.  Moving the constant to the right and multiplying by 64 gives $a + 64b = \frac{-9}{16}$.  Regardless of the specific values of $a$ and $b$, the left-hand side is an integer but the right-hand side is not.  This is a contradiction, so $\frac{1}{4}$ cannot be a root of the polynomial if $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$.